# Is there a way to solve this heat equation IBVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

I have ran into the following Heat equation IBVP, but I am not quite sure how to solve it as it has these time dependent boundary conditions

$$ v_t = kv_{xx} \ \  \ \  \ \  ( 0 \le x \le \infty, \ \ 0 < t < \infty) ,$$
$$ v(x,0) = \delta (x - x_0) \ \  \ \  \ \  \mathrm{for} \ \ t = 0, \ \ x_0 > 0  $$
$$ v(x  = ((2kt) ^{1 /2k}), ((2kt) ^{1 /2k})) = 0  $$
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} v(x, ((2kt) ^{1 /2k})) = 0 . $$

How to solve this problem ? 
Thanks.

**Edit:** 
How I got to this problem.

Consider the IBVP
$$v_p = v_q + kp^{2k - 1}v_{qq}$$
$$ v(q,0) = \delta (q - q_0) \ \  \ \  \ \  \mathrm{for} \ \ p = 0, \ \ q_0 > 0  $$
$$ v(0, p) = 0  $$
$$ \lim_{q\to\infty} v(q, p) = 0 . $$

Let us make transformation to eliminate the first term
in the right-hand side
$$
x = q + p.%
$$
After that Eq. reads:
$$
v_p = k p^{2k - 1}v_{xx}.%
$$
Introduce now new variable $t= p^{2k}/2k$, then our Eqn reduces to the conventional heat equation
$$ v_t = kv_{xx}$$

The initial condition $v(q,0) = \delta(q - q_0)$ in new
variables reads $v(x,0) = \delta(x - q_0)$.
Then, the boundary condition $v(0,p) = 0$ in the new variables
becomes:
$$
v\left[x = (2kt)^{1/2k},(2kt)^{1/2k}\right] = 0. 
$$
I hope this helps in resolving any ambiguities, in my OP.

Comment: Does the third line mean $v(y, ((2kt) ^{1 /2k})) = 0$, $y>0$?

Comment: @Andrew, I have revised the third equation, I hope this representation is clearer.

Comment: I meant this line: $v(x  + ((2kt) ^{1 /2k}), ((2kt) ^{1 /2k})) = 0$.

Comment: @Andrew, Yes indeed, sorry about that, the first parameter is the x counter part.

Comment: @Andrew, it is meant to have the x and the other term.

Comment: @Andrew, I have revised that condition, Sorry there was typo in there, now it is in the correct form.

Comment: @Andrew, Do you have any suggestions how I might approach this.

Comment: Is it proven that a solution exists? It is the first BVP for the region $x  > (2kt) ^{1 /2k}$, but a possibility of continuation of the solution to the domain $x>0$ is an extra condition.

Comment: @Andrew, We have no proof that there is a solution, we managed to fit the initial condition, but the boundary condition gave rise to an integral equation problem, which you have seen on my math overflow post. http://mathoverflow.net/q/240176/18929

Comment: @Andrew, To give you a bit more context, this problem originated as non linear second order pde, after some reductions we got here.

Comment: The problem with solution existence here is as follows. Subtracting from $v$ the fundamental solution for the heat equation $Z(x−x0,t)$ leads to the first BVP, which has a unique solution. Solutions of the heat equation are analytic wrt to $x$ variable. So if you demand that $v$ is a solution in the domain $x>0$ it means it can be analytically continued in a larger domain. Locally it could be done via Cauchy-Covalevsky theorem. But it just can happen that there is no global continuation. It's the same situation as for analytical functions which are not necessarily continued to an given domain.

Comment: Also by the dilation $(x,t)\to(x,kt)$ one can get $k=1$ in the heat equation. But the line of zero value $x=(2t)^{1/2k}$ still has parameter $k$. Is it OK with your model?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on the solution existence. I will think about that, as per your other comment, if I understand correctly, if such a dilation was carried out then the boundary conditions will also need changing, basically, by the same substitution, but to me it is kind of attractive to keep k around as it is a parameter in my model, which allows me to get to several solution cases.

Comment: @Andrew, I have a couple of questions. Do you think instead of just trying to find a solution, I should invest the time in finding a proof of it's existence first in this case ? Assuming a solution did exist, Do you think there might be a conformal mapping under which this problem might become easier to solve ?

Comment: I still don't get that is the value of $x$ in $v(x  - ((2kt) ^{1 /2k}), ((2kt) ^{1 /2k})) = 0$? Should it be $v( (2kt) ^{1 /2k}, (2kt) ^{1 /2k}) = 0$?

Comment: You are right I had missed typed that it is x = this value,  I can see how this was misleading.  I sincerely apologize.  It is just the way you said it in your comment.

Comment: I have revised it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z(x,t)=(4\pi k t)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/(4kt)}$ be the fundamental solution of the heat equation and denote 
$$G(x,x_0,t)=Z(x-x_0,t)-Z(x+x_0,t)$$ 
the Green's function of the first BVP in the domain $x>0$. Then 
$$
v(q,p)= e^{\large q_0-q-\frac{p^{2 k}}{4 k}} G\left(q,q_0,\frac{p^{2 k}}{2 k}\right).
$$
is the required solution.

Comment: Except the BC is not $v(t,t)=0$ anymore (now that the OP has been edited).

Comment: @Andrew, I am not sure how the boundary condition can be written like so, I am sorry if I misunderstood your comment and mislead you. The reason there is an x and t term in the initial condition is due to a Galilean transformation. I will update my post to show my workings, how I got to the heat equation, hopefully that will remove any ambiguities.

Comment: @Andrew, I have updated my post, please have a look.

Comment: Hi Andrew,  Can you please also explain why the boundary condition can be written like that?

Comment: It was left from the previous answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew,  I will shortly verify your answer and accept if it Checks out. I do want to ask you for one last favour.  Can you  please share how you derived this answer ? I have another similar problem to solve

Comment: And it will be very educational for me.  Thank you so much for your

Comment: Help. You are a life saver.

Comment: The similar problem I am interested in is,  one in which my starting non linear Pde has coeff

Comment: Scalar coefficients a and b for the two right hand terms. It's a slight generalisation of my model.

Comment: After your change $t= p^{2k}/2k$ turns into a parabolic one with constant coefficients. To satisfy the boundary condition Green's function of the first BVP was taken. To satisfy the equation solution was sought in the form $v(q,q_0,t)=G(q,q_0,t)u(q,q_0,t)$. To satisfy the initial condition one should impose on $u$ an additional condition $u(q_0,q_0,0)=1$. It turns out that $u$ has a closed form. If your problem is different just in a couple of constants, perhaps the solution can be sought in the form $Ge^{\alpha (q-q_0)+\beta t}$.